# ViewPager and Custom Adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have set up a ViewPager with a custom Adapter. That Adapter caches Fragments it shows. Code looks like this:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment f = getCachedFragment(position);
    if (f == null) {
        //create and add fragment to cachedFragments
    }
    System.out.println("getItem: Fragment named:" + mTabs.get(position).clss.getSimpleName() + " with Hash " + f.hashCode());
    return f;
}
```

Everything works fine. Except that the initial Fragments shown by the Fragment don't appear to be created using the `getItem()` method.

I have verified that 2 different kinds of fragments are being initiated, one with the `getItem()` method, and another one in a miraculous way I'm not able to explain. The Problem is that properly created one isn't the fragment which is being shown, so trying to access it and manipulate a view on it will fail, since `onCreateView()` has never been called.

As you can see every fragment created or retrieved is logged in chat with the corresponding hashCode. In addition to that I have added another `system.out` which tells me about new instances of a fragment.

Now, when I am on index 0 of the ViewPager, the fragment for index 1 is loaded as well, but not using `getItem()`. My Question is, how is that Fragment for index 1 initiated? I checked ViewPagerAdapter documentation but it doesnt provide any kind of solution since it just says it uses `getItem()` to get the corresponding Item.

Any pointer in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you do not want to second page is loaded when you are on page 1 ?

Comment: i do want it to be loaded, but i am wondering how it is loaded, since its not using the getItem method, which should be the proper way for the view to retrieve its fragments

Comment: I think you should use FragmentStatePagerAdapter. This adapter caches all the past visible Fragments in it automatically and only displays the visible Fragment and left right siblings of it.

Comment: ok, to make this clear. The problem isnt that the adapter caches the fragments, the problem is that apparently uses instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) to create objects. so i just overrode the method, to provide my own method. But if i just use my getItem() Method instead, the viewpager doesnt show anything at all.